# Sorting Words and Numbers from a file in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, file, sorting

I have been tasked with writing a function that takes a string reference and an integer reference parameter. The function must scan a .txt file and set the reference parameters to the name of the player with the highest score and the corresponding score.
This is written in the scores.txt file I must reference:

```
Ronaldo
10400
Didier
9800
Pele
12300
kaka
8400
Cristiano
8000
```

I currently have this much coding wrote however I am stuck as to how I am suppose to match the names up with the score since they have to be in no particular order. Within my coding I sort the numbers from greatest to least but I am not sure if this is needed or not.

```
FILE *input;
char name[name_len];
double score[score_len];
int a;
int b;
double placeholder;

input = fopen("scores.txt", "r");

if (input == NULL)
{
    printf("\n Cannot open scores.txt for input\n");
}
for (a =0; a < 5; ++a)
fscanf(input, "%s%lf", name, score);

for (a = 0; a < 5; ++a)                                     /* Repeats the step until three numbers are sorted*/
{
    for (b = a + 1; b < 5; ++b)                             /* Repeats until the last two numbers are sorted*/
    {
        if (score[a] < score[b])                                /* Sorts the 3 numbers using a placeholder to exchange the numbers in the array*/
        {
            placeholder = score[a];
            score[a] = score[b];
            score[b] = placeholder;
        }

    }
}


fclose(input);
return 0;
```

Any help regarding the solution or how I can move forward is much appreciated.

Comment: If these are the complete requirements, you don't need to sort. Just keep track of the largest score seen so far while reading your input file. If you find a larger score, store it with the corresponding name.

Comment: Also, this is tagged as C but you mention references. Did you mean to tag as C++?

Comment: The answer is "Pele" with a score of "12300". The code already reads the name and the corresponding score in one `fscanf`. All you need to do is compare the score with the best score seen so far. If the new score is better, then `strcpy` the `name` into another string, and update the best score.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just read the number and name in, and replace the value of the score and the name if its bigger.

```
char name[name_len];
double score[score_len];
char highScoreName[name_len];
double highScore = 0;
...
for (int a = 0; a < 5; ++a) 
   {
   fscanf(input, "%s %lf", name, score[a]);
   if (highScore < score[a]) 
   {
      highScore = score[a];
      strcpy(highScoreName, name);
   }
}
```

Comment: I have updated my code to reflect the changes you told me to make: 
    
 `input = fopen("scores.txt", "r");

 if (input == NULL)
 {
  printf("\n Cannot open scores.txt for input\n");
 }
 for (a = 0; a < 5; ++a)
 {
  fscanf(input, "%s%lf", name, score);
  if (highscore < score[a])
  {
   highscore = score[a];
   strcpy(highscorename, name);
  }
 }

 printf(" The highscore is %s with %f points.", highscorename, score);
 printf("\n\n");

 fclose(input);`

However now visual studio is telling me that fopen, fscanf and strncpy are unsafe. Do you know why this would be?

Comment: Also I get the error 'printf' : format string '%f' requires an argument of type 'double', but variadic argument 2 has type 'double*' why would I be getting this error aswell??

Comment: The `unsafe` warning may be because visual studio sees that `input` can be `NULL` and fail to open, but you don't actually do anything about it except print a message. You should return 1 which exits the program before trying a operation on a potentially invalid file descriptor. as for `printf`, the warning is self explanatory... score is of type `double *` you want to be printing `highScore`.

Comment: Where should I put the "return 1" to? I placed it at the end of my coding where I previously had "return 0" but I still get the errors. Thanks

Comment: inside the `if (input == NULL){}` statement. That way the program exits if the file fails to open, and you don't try to call `fscanf`, etc on an invalid file pointer.

Comment: Thanks... although now I am only getting "The highscore is Ronaldo with 10400 points" It doesn't seem to be searching through the program to look for players with a higher score... Any thoughts on why this is?

Comment: Have you tried anything to debug? Perhaps add print statements or some sort of check?

Comment: To me it looks like it is a looping issue with the if statement. it doesn't seem to be working properly. I previously had one that I wrote up and it was giving me a lot of errors so I am now using the one that you suggested. Was this working properly for you and giving pele as the highscore?

Comment: I'm not actually running your code at all, I'm just looking at it. Right now I don't see any glaring errors, try printing the values of your variables every iteration of the for loop to see what it's doing (or use a debugger...). That might give you (and someone helping you) a better idea.

Comment: That's not what I had in mind. It's always a good idea to try compiling the code.